# Not Getting IO Exception on Closing browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have issue with the spring boot application. I have a logic that will write to the response.

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public void  getdata(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
    
        ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        nameList.add("John");
        nameList.add("Mary");
        nameList.add("Sean");
        nameList.add("Peter");

        try {
            for (String s : nameList)
            {
                PrintWriter writer  =response.getWriter();
                writer.write(s + "\r\n");
                writer.flush();
            System.out.println("Writen " + s);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       
    }
```

After writing the first name it waits for 5 seconds, in the mean while close the browser but it still keeps on writing to the writer.
i was hoping to get an IOError (like writer closed) but it continues the execution

I have tried set HTTPSession too but the session closes after the method has completed it procedure

This ia my pom

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and this is the output

```
Writen John
Writen Mary
Writen Sean
Writen Peter
```

i tried with session i thought session would be killed on browser close. i also tried with get output stream still same

Comment: This won't happen. The container is buffering the entire response to see how long it is before sending, so it can set the Content-Length header. You could try setting chunked transfer mode, if that's possible.

Comment: No, it isn't possible.